# iOS/Objective C: Code Explaination

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface CustomAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subTitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coords title:(NSString *)aTitle andSubtitle:(NSString*)aSubtitle;

@end
```

I'm doing a tutorial which has the code above.

My questions:

1. What's the difference between defining a variable in braces vs. @property?
2. Why do we need to define the variables in both places?
3. What's the difference between declaring #import  in .h vs .m file?

Please answer all three questions.

Comment: 1st... inorder to access the variables in other class we use @property... if you don't then you cant use in other classes.... 2nd if you declare with 'property' you no need to again declare them.... 3rd-- couldnt get you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring the variable between the braces has the effect of actually creating the storage for the variable.

`@property` declarations will accessor methods and automatically generate the backing ivar for you, which makes the first declarations redundant. So you can strip the declaration from between the curly braces and just keep your property declarations.

The autosynthesized ivar will have a leading underscore which makes it much clearer when you are directly accessing the ivar or going through the accessors e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyThing *myThing;
```

will be available in your class either directly with

```
_myThing = [[MyThing alloc] init];
```

or through the accessors

```
[self setMyThing:[[MyThing alloc] init]];
```

Generally most of the time going through the accessors is what you want unless you are inside overridden accessor methods.

---

There was a time when `@property` and `@synthesize` would only generate the accessor methods for you and you had to take care of making sure storage was created for their use - declare a the ivar between the curly braces.

Then things moved on and `@property` and `@synthesize` were all you required and the backing ivar would be automatically synthesised.

The current state of play is that the `@property` is all that is required (in most cases) and the `@synthesize` is done implicitly.

---

## Import

There is no technical difference the statement literally just grabs the contents of the file you are importing and dumps them in it's place.

You need need to be careful of circular dependencies

```
FileA           | FileB
----------------+----------------
#import "FileB" | #import "FileA"
                |
```

which will literally become

```
FileA           |<-
----------------|  \
#import "FileB" |  /
#import "FileA" |-'
```

and

```
FileB           |<-
----------------|  \
#import "FileA" |  /
#import "FileB" |-'
```

both files will be in a circular loop trying to import themselves e.g. this just won't work.

So the easiest way to avoid this problem is to do the minimum amount of importing in your header.

If you need to reference a class in your header then use a forward declaration (`@class`)

So you end up with this

```
@class MyClass

@interface MyOtherClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass *mything;

@end
```

you have basically told the compiler that `MyClass` exists and so it's OK for you to reference it.

You then can import the actual header for `MyClass` in the implementation file.

```
#import "MyOtherClass.h"
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyOtherClass

@end
```

Comment: This is correct...just as an addition, if you let the compiler auto-synthesize, your backing iVars will be created (invisibly) with leading underscores. For example, if you had a property

    @property BOOL myProperty

And you did not manually synthesize it in the .m file, you could directly access the backing iVar using _myProperty.

Most of the time you want to use the generated accessor anyway (e.g., self.myProperty = YES) but it's still important to know this.

Answer (score 3):

> `1.` What's the difference between defining a variable in braces vs.
>   @property?

```
    @interface XXX:YYY 
    {
       place for ivars
    }
    place for properties. ivars prefixed with _(underscore) gets created automatically in new compiler.
    @end
```

> `2.`  Why do we need to define the variables in both places?

This is old style, now it is merely done. Only `@property` is enough.

> `3.` What's the difference between declaring #import in .h vs .m file?

If you want some objects of class as a property you define it in .h, and if you want only in implementation than you import in .m.

> If you put all your #imports in the header files, then no two classes
>   can mutually depend on each other, because a file can't import a file
>   that imports it. If you put the #import in the implementation file, on
>   the other hand, the problem goes away.

An extract from Chuck, [Best practice and rationale: #import in .m or .h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429888/best-practice-and-rationale-import-in-m-or-h)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What's the difference between defining a variable in braces vs.
>   @property?

Because `@property` defines attitude of variable as well its accessibility limit, if you dont write `@property` it will also work, but if you want compiler to automatically create getter and setter method for variable then use `@property` and `@synthesize` it in .m file.

> 2) Why do we need to define the variables in both places?

second half of first answer includes the answer of it. brief 'To Define setter & getter method as well its accessibility'

> 3) What's the difference between declaring `#import` in .h vs .m file?

If you import use it in .h file, it will be available to all the subclasses of that Class, while if you import in .m file it will be available(scope) only to .m file

Answer (score 1):

1. Within the braces, you can declare any instance variables that you wish. Outside of the braces is where you declare `@properties`, which automatically generate a getter and setter for the object, and any non-private methods you define in your implementation file.
2. As @Anoop Vidya mentions, declaring variables in both places is now redundant and not necessary.
3. A general rule of thumb for importing files: files that import each other create runtime errors. Therefore, abide by the following rules:

> If you need an instance variable of another class, import the other class in your header with `@class`, and then `#import` it in the implementation file.
>
> If you do not need to create an ivar from another class you've created, then simply `#import` it into your implementation file.

If you still experience mutual dependence problems after following these steps, then you probably need to rethink your design.